# Как просмотреть содержимое вектора, в котором записана собственная структура?

Tags: c++, структуры, vector, вектор

У меня есть структура, которая записывается в вектор. Но хочется убедиться, что программа работает верно. Для этого хочу посмотреть содержимое вектора, но не совсем понимаю, как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Assembler_Command
{
    int address;
    int operand;
    string command;
    string strOperand;
};

vector<Assembler_Command> assembler;
set<string> variables;
int current_address = 0, current_num_row = 0;
bool end_programm = false;

void Add_Assembler_Command(string command, string strOperand, int operand = 0)
{
    Assembler_Command assembler_cmd;
    assembler_cmd.address = current_address++;
    assembler_cmd.command = command;
    assembler_cmd.strOperand = strOperand;
    assembler_cmd.operand = operand;
    assembler.push_back(assembler_cmd);
}

int Processing_Command(string command, string params)
{
    if (command == "REM")
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (command == "INPUT")
    {
        if (params.size() == 1 && (params[0] >= 'A' && params[0] <= 'Z'))
        {
            variables.insert(params);
            Add_Assembler_Command("READ", params);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    string params = "A";
    string command = "INPUT";
    Processing_Command(command, params);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит "просмотреть"? В отладчике? Выполнить отладочный вывод содержимого вектора?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как организовать вывод содержимого вектора

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть более красивое и надежное решение. Нужно определить оператор operator<< для всех интересующих структур. И тогда все будет "магическим образом" работать. Для начала сделаем для структуры Assembler_Command

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Assembler_Command& command) {
  os << "{address:" << command.address << ", operand: " << command.operand << ", command: " << command.command << ", operand: " << command.operand << "}";
  return os; // это обязательно в конце
}
```

выглядит страшненько, но считайте, что os - это просто std::cout и нужно передать ссылку на Ваш объект.

Все, теперь можно делать вот так

```
Assembler_Command cmd;
//...
std::cout << cmd;
```

более того, можно даже в файл выводить или в std::cerr.

Теперь вторая половина квеста - это вектор. Тут есть много идей, но суть та же. Я обычно копипащу готовый код, который выводит шаблонный вектор (и оно работает для любого вектора)

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    for (auto& el : vec)
    {
        os << el << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}
```

(взято тут https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)

все, теперь можно выводить в консоль любой вектор прям вот так

```
std::vector<int> x;
std::cout << x;
```

Правда лучше чуточку доделать вывод. Я люблю вот такой код

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    os << "[ ";
    for (auto& el : vec)
    {
        os << el << ' ';
    }
    os << "]";
    return os;
}
```

С минимальными переделками (заголовок функции) этот код может выводить и std::set (в котором хранятся какие то переменные)

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::set<T>& st) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Вопрос в том, как организовать вывод содержимого вектора

Как-то так устроит?

```
for(const auto& e: assembler)
{
    cout << "address: " << e.address << endl;
    cout << "operand: " << e.operand << endl;
    cout << "command: " << e.command << endl;
    cout << "operand: " << e.strOperand << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

начиная со стандарта 17 можно так сделать

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>


struct Assembler_Command
{
    int address;
    int operand;
   std::string command;
   std::string strOperand;
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<Assembler_Command> assembler {{1, 1, "Command 1","strOperand 1"}, {2, 2, "Command 2","strOperand 2"}}; //инициализировать можно теперь так 
   for (const auto&[address, operaand, command, strOperand]:assembler)///Теперь можно получить доступ к ее членам с помощью декомпозиции.
   {
      std::cout <<"\n ID     \t"<<address 
                <<"\n Name   \t"<<operaand 
                <<"\n Role   \t"<<command
                <<"\n Salary \t"<<strOperand <<std::endl;
   }
   
   assembler.at(0).address=4; //изменить отдельные поля 
   assembler.at(0).command="Broo";

   
    for (const auto&[address, operaand, command, strOperand]:assembler)
   {
      std::cout <<"\n ID     \t"<<address // можно выводить только то что нужно 
               
                <<"\n Role   \t"<<command
                 <<std::endl;
   }

}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]